# How to open only one popover

Tags: reactjs, antd

Using Ant Design, I made a table that renders multiple records with actions as table rows. The columns are as follows:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    key: '_id',
    render: record => getFullName(record),
  },
  {
    key: 'action',
    align: 'center',
    render: (record) => {
      const content = (
        <Row type="flex" gutter={8}>
          <Col>
            <EditAccountModal closePopover={this.closePopover} agent={record} />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Button
              type="danger"
              onClick={() => this.handleRemoveAgent(record)}
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      );
      return (
        <Popover
          content={content}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          trigger="click"
          onVisibleChange={this.onVisibleChange}
        >
          <Icon className="account-action-button" type="ellipsis" />
        </Popover>
      );
    },
  },
];
```

The problem is that clicking on one popover opens all of the records' popovers; the visible state becomes true for all popovers. I only need the one I clicked to open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have all of the popovers bound to a single value: `visible={this.state.visible}`. So that single value controls visibility for ALL of them.

What you need to do is track the visibility for each individual one. You can either keep an array of booleans corresponding to each popover, and toggle those individually. Or you can put the popover into its own component which has an internal state that tracks the visibility of itself.

Comment: I think the option of making a separate component makes more sense. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean? do you have a sample example?

Comment: You just saved my day!!